# My profile wrongly says that I have not asked any questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, profile-page

I was looking for the question I have asked. (I have found it, since.)

I went to my profile.

[My profile](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/3255/nicolas-barbulesco?tab=questions) says :

“0 Questions” [sic]

“You have not asked any questions”

This is wrong.

I have asked one question, and I have even got an answer.

Comment: @Mike — I am not asking for help here. Actually, it is the opposite. I am reporting a bug.

Comment: To elaborate on Nick Craver's answer, the question was deleted by the Stack Exchange system processes after being closed as off-topic.  If you'd like to recover that question so you can ask again elsewhere in the SE network, we can assist with that.  If you merely want the question to show up in your profile again, that's not really worthy of un-deleting.

Comment: @Mike — [Here is a screen photo of what I have in my profile.](http://pbrd.co/1crvh1V)

Answer (score 3):

Deleted content is not shown in your profile, the counts are for non-deleted content and are accurate showing 0 right now.